# htaccess rewrite with 2nd parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently I'm using this rule to redirect to profile page, which works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/ ./profile.php?do=view&profileid=$1 [L,NC]
```

The problem is that I need to pass a second parameter, so the url
`profile/1/Chris/2` to point to 
`profile.php?do=view&profileid=$1&tab=2`

Is there any simple way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly this is possible:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(\d+)/[^/]+/(\d+)/?$ /profile.php?do=view&profileid=$1&tab=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(\d+)/? /profile.php?do=view&profileid=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

UPDATE: considering your additional comment about how that second parameter is to be treated this probably implements that specific requirement:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(\d+)/[^/]+/.+ /profile.php?do=view&profileid=$1&tab=2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(\d+)/? /profile.php?do=view&profileid=$1 [END]
```

Comment: Works fine thank you. Just a question if your don't mind. Why this link profile/5/christeris-php-freelancer/2/ works and the link profile/5/christeris-php-freelancer/partners/ does not works? .... The target link should be always &tab=2 what ever parameter is.

Comment: I added an update to the question. That specific required was not clear to me from your original question.